# How to capture form submit from a page that has multiple forms

Tags: jquery, forms, laravel, submit, capture

I have a table that contains invoices which means there are multiple rows, each row contains a form in which the user can submit a payment for, how can I intercept the correct form's submit with jquery?

Right now I can intercept the first form's submit but I need this to be more versatile and allow me to intercept any form's submit.

Any help is appreciated, thank you for your time.

My current code:

payment.blade.php

`<form action="{{'/users/payment'}}" method="post" id="checkout-form">`

checkout.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log("Checkout.js is running!");
Stripe.setPublishableKey('...');

var $form = $('form:last');
console.log($form);
$form.submit(function (event) {
    console.log("form submit event clicked");
    $('charge-error').addClass('hidden');
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
    if ($('#paymentMethod').val() == 'Saved Card') {
        console.log("reaching if statement");
        // No new card is used so just submit the form.
        $form.get(0).submit();
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log("reaching else statement");
        console.log($('#card-number').val());

        Stripe.card.createToken({
            number: $('#card-number').val(),
            cvc: $('#card-cvc').val(),
            exp_month: $('#card-expiry-month').val(),
            exp_year: $('#card-expiry-year').val()
        }, stripeResponseHandler);
        return false;
    }
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    if (response.error) {
        console.log("reaching error statement");
        $('#charge-error').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#charge-error').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        console.log("reaching successful response statement");
        var token = response.id;
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to our local server:
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));

        // Submit the form:
        $form.get(0).submit();
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your form selector

```
var $form = $("form");
```

Then

```
$form.submit(function(){
  //Every form submit will trigger this function
});
```

To access the child elements of a form

```
$form.submit(function(){
  $this = $(this);
  var number = $this.find('#card-number').val(),
  cvc = $this.find('#card-cvc').val(),
  exp_month = $this.find('#card-expiry-month').val(),
  exp_year = $this.find('#card-expiry-year').val();      
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! This worked for me! However I have a question about the child inputs for the form like card-number and card-name. How can I access these now? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Could you also inform me as how to submit the form? I currently return false so i can send my payment information to my payment processor and then when i receive the information back from the payment processor I need to submit the form.

Comment: All you have to do is call `$this.submit()` when you are ready to submit . @rapid3642